# How to wait for '>' in SIM900 message format

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, sim900

Hello all I am trying to send sms using `SIM900` and `PIC18F2520`. I have button attached to pin of MCU. So whenever the button is pressed, sms should be sent.Following is the code I am using to send SMS:

```
if(PORTCbits.RC1==1)
{
  DelayMs(10);
  if(PORTCbits.RC1==1)
  {
    UARTsend("AT+CMGS=\"99********\"\r ");
    DelayMs(100);
    UARTsend("Hello World");
    DelayMs(10);
    UARTsend("\x1A ");
    DelayMs(10);
 }
}
```

Now when I run it in debug mode, I receive sms. But when I program the device, what happens is it send `AT+CMGS` command and then send `Hello world` and `\x1A`. After sending all these things, then it shows `>`, that means now it wait for the message content. I dont know why it is happening. I have given the proper delay after `AT+CMGS`. I tried increasing the delay but again no changes.
How to wait for `>` while sending sms. Please help

[image]

Comment: Easiest way is to write a function which returns the latest character received on UART. And then block with a while loop:
`while(GSM_uart_recieve() != '>');` . Of course it can be improved with a timer to make a simple timeout functionality to ensure you won't stuck in the while loop if the module does not answer.

Comment: You can handle it with and ISR as well, if you want a non-blocking solution. So you can check all received byte in the **UART receive complete** interrupt and set a flag if `>` is received and so on.

Comment: Yes I have tried receiving it  using `if(ReadUSART()=='>')` and then send sms. but it never enters in the if condition. I have read somewhere that sim900 also sends some <CR><LF> maybe because of these its not entering in if condition. How to process them

Comment: What is the return value of `ReadUSART()`?

Comment: [ReadUSART()](http://www.jgorasia.com/Files/UBWdemos/Documentation/periph-lib/USART.htm#_Toc178000533) return a byte from UART. I have partially solved the problem by increasing the delay to 5sec after sending `AT+CMGS` so now its working but I think thats not the proper solution to it. It should check if it reads `>` and then send the message. I am trying it.

Comment: try to add a "\n" like this:"AT+CMGS=\"99********\"\r\n "

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in receiving certain character on UART irrespective of time, then check UART interrupt section. You can do like this,
-Enable UART reception interrupt.
- In while(1) -Infinite loop
-As soon as it receive data then check whether it is expected or not. (In your case it will be'>')
-And when you receive the expected data you can either disable interrupt, stop communication or go for other task.